Spring Boot Using Webclient for Post API Call
I am trying to make a POST API call, and take the response and map it to a model that I have created. The issue I am having is the API response Json has more fields than my model (don't need most of them) and it has a header that is returned (also don't need that data) so it is not mapping correctly to my model
Model
public class Movie {
   public String title;
   public String movieStudio;
   public String year;

   //Getter and Setters etc.
}

Response Json
{
   "Header": {
      "Status" : "Success",
      "Field" : "value"
   },
   Movies : [ {    //THIS WILL ALWAYS RETURN ONLY 1 MOVIE
      "Title" : "Gone with the wind",
      "actor" : "Tom Cruze",
      "lenght" : "120min",
      "movieStudio" : "MGM",
      "year" : "1958",
      "type" : "drama",
      "releaseDate" : "05-21-1958"
   } ]
}
      

API Call
//Setup Webclinet client

Movie response = client.post()
   .uri("/movies")
   .bodyValue("JsonString")
   .retrieve()
   .bodyToMono(Movie.class)
   .block();

return response


How would I go about mapping the few fields that I need from the API response to a new Movie object, and i can return?
Right now, this returns a movie object that has null values.
Thank You in Advance
